# How can this vector be ortogonal to the plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the planes equation below here:
$$
3\cdot x -  y +3 \cdot z = 3
$$
And i have this question below:

Determine a parameter representation of the line L that passes the origin and is orthogonal to the plane

The exam answer is:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}
=t
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\-1\\3
\end{bmatrix},\quad t\in \mathbb R.
$$

A vector that is ortogonal is $n\cdot v = 0$?

But when I take this vector

$$
3\cdot 3-1\cdot-1+3\cdot 3 = 19\,?
$$
How can this vector be ortogonal to the plane $$3x-y+3z = 3\,?$$

Comment: What do you mean "But when i take this vector 33-1-1+33"?

Comment: Also, use Mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: 3*3-1*1+3*3 = 19 when you take the t-vector and the planes-equation?

Comment: I have no idea what you tried to say with that last comment. Also, use MathJax.

Comment: I took the t-vector times normal-vector of the plane and got 19? @5xum

Comment: What is "the t-vector"? Also, for the last time, use MathJax.

Comment: t(3,-1,3) @5xum Where is there an tutorial on MathJax?

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: I have added some MathJax @5xum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X(x,y,z)$ and $U(u,v,w)$ are two points in the plane, then a vector within the plane is $\overrightarrow{XU}=(u-x,v-y,w-z)$.
You can check that $(3,-1,3)$ is perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{XU}$